# show Woocommerce checkout page depending on product category

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a question, need to show the category in the checkout plugins WooCommerce, achievement show with the following code

```
<td class="product-cat" >
    <?php
    $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $product_cat = $term->name;
        }
    echo $product_cat ; ?>
</td>
```

throws me the courage, but I fling with spaces, and I need this value to validate another field, I mean, if category = 1, jquery show another input, if not hidden

but to me the value space, I can not make it work I validation

Deputy output code

```
<td class="product-cat">Video Clases</td>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use trim() function to strip white spaces.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Try this one:

```
<td class="product-cat" ><?php
                        $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
                            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                               $product_cat = $term->name;
                            }
                            echo trim($product_cat) ;

                    ?></td>
```

Comment: Try your code, but I still displayed with spaces.

try placing the trim in the variable $ terms, but the page falls, another possible solution?

Thanks for your answer mertizci